# Is it possible to get synchronous spark request-reply response?

Tags: apache-spark

This might be a old question.But I could not find any solutions.I am able to get request-reply response from synchronous kafka.But I need to get the same response from spark application where I calculate aggregations.How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Apache incubator project called [Livy](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/) exactly for this purpose.
Their [documentation](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html) is not bad and pretty simple and straight forward.